# Spring query String simple validation?

Tags: java, spring, string, validation, spring-boot

Is there a way to query a String request that isn't tied to anything in particular. I know of Spring annotations with @Validation, but I'm looking for something when the query is not tied to an object.

For example, the request is one String value, and then some business logic works with that string. That string should not be null and at least 3 characters long. Is there where to check this and send an appropriate error response or do you have to do it manually?

Something similar to using Joi in Express/Node.js (note how the schema is made on the spot instead of referring to an object):

```
app.post('/api/courses', (req, res) => {
            const schema = {
                name: Joi.string().min(3).required()
            }

            const result = Joi.validate(req.body, schema);
            //check result if error, otherwise continue
        }
```

Here is a Spring/Java representation of what I'm looking for,

```
@GetMapping
public String getSumOfWord(@RequestParam String word){
    //Validate here that word is non-empty and > 3 characters

    //Buisness logic (i.e. calculate letter total where a = 1, b = 2 etc.)
}
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Post code illustrating what you want to achieve.

Comment: @JBNizet I've added more details to question.

Comment: What do you mean by *"when the query is not tied to an object"*? Show examples with Spring code of what you mean, so we can understand the context of what you're asking.

Comment: @Andreas I've edited the question with Spring code.

Comment: Seems like you may be looking something along the lines of https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/.

Answer (score 1):

You can do your size validations with @Size along with @RequestParam

```
@GetMapping
public String getSumOfWord(@RequestParam @Size(min= 1, max = 3 , message = "word must be less than 3 characters") String word){

}
```